# Pass Parameter to JS function of TabContainer OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net

I'm assigning a JS function to OnClientClick property of a TabContainer like this

```
TabContainer1.Tabs[0].OnClientClick="JSTest"
```

I would like to know how I can pass a parameter to this function JSTest. I tried this

```
TabContainer1.Tabs[0].OnClientClick="JSTest('1');"
```

but this doesn't work. It would be great if you could help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error!! What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Code behind File**

```
TabContainer1.Tabs[0].OnClientClick = "function(){onShow(1);}";
```

**in .js file...**

```
function onShow(GetVal) {
    alert(GetVal);
}
```

Comment: I checked it in my environment and it's working fine. Give me comment!! If it helps you..